# What is the best way to store document specific settings in a Core Data Document?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, conceptual

I'm using a `NSPersistantDocument` backed by Core Data in my application.

Each document has a number of settings that are only relevant to that document. For example the document needs to hold the unique ID of an Address Book Group, to update it at a later date.

The way I'm thinking of approaching this is to have another model, `DocumentSetting`, which has two attributes; a key and a value, which hold `NSString`'s.

Ideally I would like something similar to `NSUserDefaults` but stored within the document.

Has anyone done this before? Are there any better way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setMetadata: method on NSPersistentStore can be used to store per-document settings.  The docs for how to go about using the store's metadata can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006453-SW4).  As advised in the docs though, there are some size limitations on what can be put in there.  If you need to store something more substantial than a few key/value pairs, I would recommend making a new entity in your data model to store such data.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian says, the persistent store's metadata is a good place for this kind of thing. Alternatively, your idea to add a separate entity work as well (I've used both methods in the past). Keep in mind that if this `DocumentSetting` entity doesn't have relationships to other entities in your document model, you can put it into a separate xcdatamodel and merge the models at runtime using `-[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:]`. At least this way you can keep your "source" model files isolated a bit.

In terms of strategy, unless you are going to have a very large number of these document settings or want to query them individually, you could use a transformable property and store an (archived) `NSDictionary` in your `DocumentSettings` entity. This would make the feel much more like the `NSUserDefaults` API which feels basically like a dictionary.